# Which is the right Stack Exchange site to ask a question about how much someone has to be paid for making an Android application?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, payment

Some people asked me to create an Android application for them, and I want to know what is the right amount of money that I have to ask them for that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no Stack Exchange suitable for such a question.

You need to do your own market research for that (like - look online to see how much people charge for similar apps).